# google text to speech api unable to find path of json key using anaconda with python on windows

Tags: python, cmd, path, anaconda, filepath

I am trying to use google clould api to use text to speech. For this it needs to access a json key which i saved to

```
C:\keys\*****.json
```

and set the path as

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\keys\*****.json"
```

when I run the sample scrip I get the error that i its not able to find the file on that path.

```
C:\Users\dsandhu\Documents\linux\googlecloud\python-docs-samples\texttospeech\testing>python sampletest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampletest.py", line 28, in <module>
    synthesize_text("hello world")
  File "sampletest.py", line 4, in synthesize_text
    client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\texttospeech_v1\gapic\text_to_speech_client.py", line 84, in __init__
    scopes=self._DEFAULT_SCOPES,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 170, in create_channel
    credentials, _ = google.auth.default(scopes=scopes)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\google\auth\_default.py", line 294, in default
    credentials, project_id = checker()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\google\auth\_default.py", line 165, in _get_explicit_environ_credentials
    os.environ[environment_vars.CREDENTIALS])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\google\auth\_default.py", line 89, in _load_credentials_from_file
    'File {} was not found.'.format(filename))
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File "C:\keys\*****.json" was not found.
```

I am using anaconda(as admin) with python to set the variable in anaconda terminal. I also tried to set it in windows cmd (set with same command) but no luck.

I am posting the scrip also in case you want to test it:

```
def synthesize_text(text):
    """Synthesizes speech from the input string of text."""
    from google.cloud import texttospeech
    client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

    #text = "Hello world"
    input_text = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(text=text)
    #input_text = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(text="Hellow world")

    # Note: the voice can also be specified by name.
    # Names of voices can be retrieved with client.list_voices().
    voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(
        language_code='en-US',
        ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.FEMALE)

    audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(
        audio_encoding=texttospeech.enums.AudioEncoding.MP3)

    response = client.synthesize_speech(input_text, voice, audio_config)

    # The response's audio_content is binary.
    with open('output.mp3', 'wb') as out:
        out.write(response.audio_content)
        print('Audio content written to file "output.mp3"')



synthesize_text("hello world")
```

using from this [link](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python)

Comment: Check if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2953843/3007402

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to do remove the quotes and do

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\keys\******.json
```

and it worked.